# Algorithm for generating random network

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

What is the best algorithm to generate a random simple (no parallel edges or self-loops) undirected graph with a given number of nodes, where each node has a number of edges that is no less than `min` and no greater than `max`?

For example, if `min = 2` and `max = 5`, I would like a graph where approximately 25% of the nodes have 2 edges, approximately 25% of the nodes have 3 edges, approximately 25% of the nodes have 4 edges, and approximately 25% of the nodes have 5 edges.

Comment: No parameter for the number of nodes?

Comment: Why do your nodes each need a specific number of edges?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's got nothing to do with coding. Maybe it would be better on [mathematics stack exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you want your choice of graphs to be unbiased in the sense that each graph (with a given number of nodes) which satisfies the constraints on the degrees of the nodes is equally likely to be constructed then this strikes me as a difficult problem since you would need to prove that your algorithm doesn't introduce any bias. There is a large literature on random graphs you could explore.

Comment: @LondonRob - why off topic? The question tags seem to be fairly general ones having to do with algorithms rather than implementation in specific languages.

Comment: it's a direct graph?

Comment: @JohnColeman There's some discussion of this exact point [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se). This is not a coding question.

Comment: @LondonRob Ok - but it seems like there is a bit of a grey area. More likely than not the question is one that comes from a particular coding problem rather than idle theoretical CS curiosity. Anyone who is able to formulate such a question and understand the answer could trivially implement it in say Python and is probably intending to (in some language) I'm inclined to see it as a language-agnostic coding question rather than a pure math question.

Comment: Can there be more than one edge between two nodes, and can there be edges from a node back to itself?

Comment: @tobias_k, no, two nodes have to be connected by at most one node, and a node cannot connect to itself. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ok, I'm down with that. Close vote retracted.

Comment: How dense are the desired graphs?

Comment: You could put each node in a pool x times (x being a random number between min and max) and then pull out pairs of nodes from that pool and add an edge for those. You might need some backtracking, though, otherwise the last pair of nodes could be the same node or a pair which already has an edge.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [random_degree_sequence_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph.html) from NetworkX, which uses an algorithm due to Bayati, Kim, and Saberi.

Comment: Could you also please explan how this algorithm works?

Comment: @MarkusWillson Sadly, the NetworkX source is [buried treasure](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/buried-treasure.html) that omits most of the subtlety of the cited paper. The idea is to draw edges according to the distribution weighted by product of degrees with a correction term, subject to the resulting residual degree sequence being realizable. I need to think about how to revise this answer, but if the asker's quality standards are not very high, then perhaps it doesn't matter.